# Select a pair of columns with 1 fixed column & other is any other column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set with 5 columns. I want to select 4 pairs of data & store them under 4 names. However I want to take 1st column for all these pairs & the other column of the pair will be any of the other 4 columns.

```
Target  Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
1       1167    56130   0.591   0.248
0       1677    47681   0.425   0.875
1       603     22006   0.462   1.401
1       489     68545   0.348   0.869
0       1479    38670   0.919   1.678
1       976     15307   0.268   1.056
1       1509    53761   0.81    1.76
1       1093    54701   0.875   1.03
0       648     68620   0.728   1.013
1       1501    58637   0.428   0.651
0       308     54036   0.814   1.084
1       1609    86235   0.136   1.29
1       817     29216   0.422   0.177
1       460     70500   0.912   1.654
1       1190    89207   0.397   0.191
1       1128    40301   0.771   1.08
```

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO !
I posted an answer that shall match your expectations. But for future use and good questions writing's sake, please read more doc about your questions - as `cbind()` is quite a basic function in data.frame handling. However, enjoy R ;)

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I would surely keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, with `df` your data.frame:

```r
dataset.list <- lapply(df[,2:dim(df)[2]],
                       function(col){
                         cbind(df[[1]], col)
                       })
```

`dataset.list` contains 4 data.frames, each built with two columns: the first of each data.frame is the 1st column, and the other is V1, V2, ..., Vn with n = ncol-1.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful.